# upgrading esapi to version 2.5.2.0 breaking isValidInput using parameter ParameterStandard

Tags: esapi

I have upgraded esapi to esapi-2.5.2.0. I downloaded esapi-2.5.2.0-configuration.jar, extracted validation.properties and ESAPI.properties to put them on classpath.
In my code i have this call ESAPI.validator().isValidInput("Parameter_Value_Default", value, "ParameterStandard", MAX_PARAMTER_VALUE_LENGTH, true) that returned true but returns false after the upgrade

It is using "ParameterStandard" that was part of validation.properties in version 2.2.3.1 but it is no longer in version 2.5.2.0.

Why ParameterStandard is missing in 2.5.2.0? What is the right way to fix isValidInput so that it returns true again? thank you

Comment: Kevin beat me to that answer but I've been deeply involved with the validation code for 4-5yrs and that isn't a default ESAPI parameter.  As a precaution I just checked out 2.1.0.1 and grepped with that parameter and it exists nowhere.  Follow Kevin's advice.

Answer (score 0):

That validation property doesn't ring a bell and doesn't sound like something we would name it, but of course I could be wrong. I've looked at the tagged esapi-2.3.1.0 code and I don't see that parameter anywhere. Here's where I would expect it to be:
https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/blob/esapi-2.2.3.1/configuration/esapi/validation.properties
(which is the version intended for production) and I don't see it in the test version either:
https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/blob/esapi-2.2.3.1/src/test/resources/esapi/validation.properties
It also in neither of the **ESAPI.properties** files from that release.

If I had to guess, I'd say that Validation.ParamterStandard is a custom value that someone on your team added. So just copy / paste it in from your old **validation.properties** to the new one and you should be good to go.